# usergroup permission issues

Tags: permissions, users, nginx

I tried deleting files on my dekstop *(highlight files, press delete)* in `/usr/share/nginx/www` but I'm getting permission denied issues.

What I did was, add `www-data` and `barsoom`(current user) to a group:

```
sudo addgroup web
usermod -a -G web barsoom
usermod -a -G web www-data
chgrp -R web /usr/share/nginx/www
```

But why can't I still delete the files in `/usr/share/nginx/www`. I'm still getting `Permission denied`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to logout and log back in after changing group membership in order to obtain the new set of privileges.  (Alternatively you can run `sg` (like su, switch user, but instead switch group)   You can see what privileges you current have by running `id`.
2. What are the permissions on those files?  Even with the group set to `web`, the group may not have the necessary write permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Usually things under /usr/share are owned by root and permissions are -rwxr-x-r-x.  The leftmost 3 characters are permissions for the root, followed by the group, followed by everyone (so only root has write access).  Did you `ls -l` to see the permissions? Changing the group owner won't change the permissions.  You need `chmod` for that.

If you *really* want to delete those files, open a terminal and:

```
cd /usr/share/nginx
sudo rm -r www
```

The `-r` is for recursive so that everything in that directory including itself will be removed.